# SQL - How can I use a level that depends on one column on other calculated column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I do that in Oracle 11g?

The problem here is that the query on `DUAL` does not recognize `APP` table.

```
SELECT APP_VER || SUBVERSION.LEVEL
  FROM APP,
       (SELECT LEVEL
          FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < APP.NUM_SUBVERSIONS) SUBVERSION
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I'm not clear what results you are trying to get-- posting sample data and expected outputs would be nice.  My guess is that you are trying to cause each row to repeat `num_subversions` times?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need one row for each possibile subvesion, you can avoid the problem with some nesting, like the following:

```
select APP_VER  , NUM_SUBVERSIONS, subversions.num
from app app
inner join 
             ( select level num
               from dual
               connect by level <= ( select max(num_subversions) from app)
             ) subversions
  on (subversions.num <= num_subversions)
```

This requires more scanning of your tables, so it may not be so efficient, but, from the names of your tables and columns, I assume you have not so many records to handle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can use Recursive With subquerying to do it:

```
with a1 (app_ver, num_subversions, lvl) as (
select app_ver, num_subversions, 1
  from app
 union all
select app.app_ver, app.num_subversions, a1.lvl + 1
  from app, a1
 where app.app_ver = a1.app_ver
       and a1.lvl < app.num_subversions)
search depth first by app_ver, num_subversions set my_order
select app_ver || lvl
  from a1;
```

Sample execution:

```
SQL> create table app as
  2  with app (app_ver, num_subversions) as (
  3  select 'A', 2 from dual union all
  4  select 'B', 3 from dual union all
  5  select 'C', 4 from dual
  6  )
  7  select app_ver, num_subversions
  8    from app a;
Table created
SQL> with a1 (app_ver, num_subversions, lvl) as (
  2  select app_ver, num_subversions, 1
  3    from app
  4   union all
  5  select app.app_ver, app.num_subversions, a1.lvl + 1
  6    from app, a1
  7   where app.app_ver = a1.app_ver
  8         and a1.lvl < app.num_subversions)
  9  search depth first by app_ver, num_subversions set my_order
 10  select app_ver || lvl
 11    from a1;
APP_VER||LVL
-----------------------------------------
A1
A2
B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
C3
C4
9 rows selected
```